# Split my filter into 2 filters one which is delegable and one which is not none-delegable

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Inside the screen onvisible, i have this filter statement to build a collection:-

```
ClearCollect(colSpareParts,ShowColumns(Filter('Spare Parts Asset Types','Asset Type ID'=varWorkOrderATID && ActiveStatus.Value="Active"),"SparePartID"));
```

Then inside a Combobox items property, i have this statement:-

```
With(
   {
      _Start: 
      Filter(
         'Spare Parts', ActiveStatus.Value="Active" And Quantity > 0 And
         StartsWith(
            Title,
            Self.SearchText
         ) And ID in (colSpareParts)
      )
   },
   Sort(
      
        _Start,
         Title
     
   )
)
```

now part of the statement is delegable and part of it is not , as follow:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1706039398421.png]

so how i can do the delegable query first, then run the none-delegable part (in operator) on the delegable results?

Thanks

Comment: The `in` operator is not delegable so to work around this, perform the delegable queries first, collect the results, and then perform the non-delegable operations on the collected results. This way, you’re performing the non-delegable operation on a smaller, already filtered data. Please see: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/delegable-alternative-for-IN-operator/td-p/652315#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20workaround%20for%20a%20multiuser%20column.,delegation%20limit.%20Then%20you%20can%20ignore%20the%20warning.

Comment: @MartinIszac thanks